# Similar images compression

Tags: image, compression, lossless-compression

I have bunch of similar images.  Those images contains different noise, but edges and histograms are very similar. I need to compress this images loselessly.
Is there any algorithm, that can use  image similarity for more efficient compression ?
I have tried to use improved compression via prediction (changed MED predictor from LOCO), but my gain was only about 0,4%

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean exactly by "similar"?  Having similar histograms isn't going to help much.  Do the images *look* the same?

You could simply try subtracting the previous image from this image, pixel by pixel and color by color, and see if the difference image is more compressible.

The next step would be to make the series of images a video, and use video compression, which can exploit more complex correlations between successive images.

Comment: Similar... they look the same by eyes. But If you substract them, you got somehow noisy images. I tried compress this noisy image, but from nature of noise, its not very well comprimable. Using video codecs is one way, but I thought if there is some kind of special image algorithm for that. If I decompress sequence, I got individual images, not video.

Answer (score 2):

If you have heard about Set Redundancy Compression ([SRC](http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~kosmas/Dissertation.pdf)) that would make your task very easy. It provides loss less and lossy image image compression techniques for set of similar images. 
 
**Min-Max differential** technique might be the one you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing "`composite -compose difference image1 image2 diff`" on sequential images (or arbitrarily order the images in some way if you don't already have an order). The 'diff' image might be very small, and you can recover image2 by doing `composite -compose difference diff image1` (or some variation).

Answer (score 0):

Are the images in gray scale or are colored. If they are gray scale ones, I have an application that I developed 7 years ago. I can try it for you.
It is based on a technique that is called Set Redundancy Compression.

If they are colored, you can try Lagarith (a video codec)

Comment: I have different data types, some are RGB, some grayscale, some float. Is your compression suitable also for video sequence ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay (one year :p) . Unfortunately no, t is not suitable for video compression

Comment: @gabis could you get in touch with me? On my profile you find the website with a contact form. thanks